# Converting Decimal to different bases

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to convert decimals to other bases in R. The function `dec2base` from the `oro.dicom` package only works for integers (as stated in its help file):

```
> dec2base(1.559,9)
[1] "1"
```

Whereas 1.559 in base 9 should be 1.5024, and I was wondering if there is another method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Rmpfr` package can do arbitrary-precision arithmetic and base conversion:

```r
library(Rmpfr)
x <- mpfr(1.559, precBits = 64, base = 10)  ## base = 10 is default
b9 <- as.numeric(format(x, base = 9))
print(b9)
## 1.502453
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would be able to multiply the number by the number of non zero decimal places and undo the operation on the backend of the dec2base command.

Comment: If I understand what you're suggesting correctly, and using for example 1.559, that would be multiplying by 1000 so `> dec2base(1559,9)
[1] "2122" ` then dividing by 1000 in base 9? So 2122/1331, which gives 1.59429

Comment: I think you are dividing the final numbers base 10.  That is incorrect.

Comment: Oh I realize my mistake, thank you. I was dividing in base 10 rather than in base 9.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you know of a way to divide in other bases in R?